# Getting the correct image url from a WordPress advanced custom field array?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

Wordpress newb.

```
$article_data = get_field('article_item');
  foreach ($article_data as $key => $item) {
    $footerImg = (!empty($item['bottom_image'])) ? $item['bottom_image'] : NULL;
    $url = implode( ', ', $footerImg );
    echo $url;

  }
```

That outputs this:

```
2345, 
67899, 
boston_skyline, 
boston_skyline.jpg, 
http://localhost:8000/bostontheme/images/2018/08/boston_skyline.jpg, 
2018-08-07 01:24:21
```

How to I grab the image strings in there so that I can do something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```

When I do this

```
print_r($item);
```

I get this output:

```
Array ( 
[bottom_image] => Array ( 
[ID] => 67899 
[id] => 67899 
[title] => boston_skyline 
[filename] => boston_skyline.jpg 
[url] => http://localhost:8000/bostontheme/images/2018/08/boston_skyline.jpg
```

Comment: Add `print_r($item);` instead and update your question with the output. BTW, this isn't a "WordPress custom field array", it's an Advanced Custom Fields array.

Comment: Hi @PeterHvD I updated the post to reflect your advice. Any thoughts on the output there of print item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want, simply, `$item["bottom_image"]["url"]`